# Google Analytics User Explorer - name user

Tags: google-analytics

I want to be able to give a name to specific users to display instead of their ID. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Is is possible to do so, if you record their name as part of a registration process. You would have to pass their name through to Google Analytics as a Custom Dimension.

However, GA's terms of service forbid the use of personally identifiable information, so it would be a violation of these terms to use names.

> You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an individual (such as a name, email address or billing information), or other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by Google.

This post by Simo Ahava has some very useful instructions on passing Custom Dimensions into GA: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/

Comment: But is it possible for me to have a personal way of identification (that I add) so I can recognise them instead of just their ID? It wouldn't necessarily have to be a real name

Comment: Do you specifically want some sort of text name that you would be able to visually recognise better, or would a randomly generated number do? UserID is the best practice for tracking users across sessions - Simo runs through implementing UserID in the blog post I linked to previously.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your intent is to try and gain access to the account on behalf of the owner.

Below are the steps outlined by en.advertisercommunicy.com:
**To initiate the process of regaining access to your Analytics account we need the following information when you fill in the [Customer form](https://support.google.com/adwords/?hl=en#topic=3119071&contact=1&ts=2839618,2839763)**
According to Google:

> (You’ll need an Adwords account to do so. A vacant account without
>   any payment works too) :

Next Steps:

> 1) The UA-XXXX-Y of the account you require access to. This can be
>   found the source code of the page which has the Analytics tracking
>   code. If don’t know how to find this just provide the website URL when
>   filling in the Adwords customer form.
>
> 2. 2) Please specify the level of access you require i.e if you require access at the [account level](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en) or at the property level. (Account
>      level :UA-XXXX, Property level (See link for "account level" :UA-XXXX-Y)

Customer form is the 4th item on the right side in the white box.

After this, according to GOogle Advertiser Help:

> Once we have the information we will get in touch with you over email
>   :   We will get in touch with the Users who have Manage and Edit
>   access to the required Analytics account asking them to directly reach
>   out to you within 2 business days. Per security process we can’t give
>   out the identity of the Administrators of the account you need access
>   t

o.